# Proposal to add math.stackexchange.com to list of destinations for Migration

Tags: feature-request, migration

I'm looking now at a question ([Existence of solution of a linear Diophantine equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561977)) which is off-topic for SO but suitable for math.stackexchange.com. I see that Closing -> Off-Topic -> Migration lists meta, superuser, tex, dba, and stats as possible destinations, but not math.

Can we add math.stackexchange.com to the list shown in Closing -> Off-Topic -> Migration?

Comment: As with all such FR - did you consult with math.SE folks that this is good idea? Also 1 question is not a reason to ask for new migration target - I'd think at least 10+ good questions a day would be needed to consider that...

Comment: Most sites shudder at the possibility of becoming a dumping ground for low-quality Stack Overflow questions. Better to suggest in comments that the OP consider posting on another site *but also that they read the other site's help site before posting*.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If you've got something against the members of that site, perhaps.  That's basically just you participating in making a site a smaller dumping ground.

Comment: @Servy the problem as I see it is that most who vote for the migration don't know the rules of the destination site well enough to know if the question is on or off topic. I could see allowing this for members with high enough reputation on **both** sites.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Most people posting comments telling people to post on another site *also* don't know the site rules well enough to only suggest it on questions that would make good questions on the target site, and telling them to read the help center is pointless.  If they didn't read the help center before posting an off topic question on the site they're on, the odds of them reading the help center before posting on a site someone told them to post their question on instead are...slim.

Comment: @Servy yes *but*, then the responsibility is on them, the OP and not on us. And for me, that is a significant difference. We can't force them to do anything, but we sure as heck can prevent one of us making a bad situation worse without any input from the OP.

Comment: I wonder if it would make sense to show a specific migration target to a user only if that user has a certain amount of rep on the target site.

Answer (score 6):

If you can answer these questions in good faith, then flag it for a moderator to migrate over.

- Is the question coherent, understandable and specific?
- Is the question *irrefutably* on-topic on the target site, and *irrefutably* off-topic *here*?

Working backards from this heuristic:

- If the question is about math in a programming context (e.g. someone has trouble with some *code* for which their method is math-based in origin, and the problem is about their *code*, then it would be on-topic for the site.  Since there is no code here, then the question is off-topic *here*.

  [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seems to be okay with this question since it is asking about a mathematical property anyway.
- The question is *not* specific since it's asking two questions in one.  So, I would rather *not* migrate this question.  It'd be a good candidate for closure under "too broad".

It's always better to deal with questions which aren't good on the site that you find them on.  This way, only one set of community members has to wring their hands over its quality rather than two sets.

Comment: I'm generally in agreement, although I have to wonder about the emphatic "irrefutably" here. So little in life is for sure; certainly not stuff found on social media such as SE. By the way, you might not be aware that heavy use of emphasis gives your prose an air of misplaced authority which I'm sure you don't intend; when I read it, I hear a John Cleese character speaking. Speaking of hand-wringing, I see there's a lot of it going on right here.

Comment: @RobertDodier:  I state "irrefutably" because sites have overlapping topics, and migration is strongly discouraged if a question is on topic on the site it's already on.